# For the random variables X,Y and Z, Is the expression E[E[X|Z]|Y] = E[X|Z] true or False given we do not know if X,Y,Z are independent or not.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given, we do not know if $X,Y,Z$ are independent or not. Will the expression $E[E[X|Z]|Y] = E[X|Z]$ hold true?

What I have tried:

Now, $E[X|Z]$ is a random variable so let $E[X|Z]$ be $A$

So, problem boils down to $E[A|Y]$ which can only be equal to $A$ if A and Y are independent.

I would like to know if my thought process is accurate or not

Comment: You are comparing in your question $E[A|Y]$ and $A$ (not $E[A]$, which by the way would not be a r.v.). In general yes these are not equal. Probably they are equal iff $A$ is $Y-$measurable but not really sure of the "only if". Anyway to see that the statement is not valid in general you can just try out the identity with $X=Z$ (see my answer)

Comment: oh boy, my apologies for that, I mistyped

Comment: Still you have issues in what you write with the new version. If A and Y are independent E[A|Y] is deterministic and equal to E[A]. So I am not sure your was really a typo...

Comment: Please accept the answer if you solved your doubt

Answer (score 1):

Just choose $X=Z$. In this case $E[X|X]=X$ and therefore:

$E[E[X|Z]|Y]=E[X|Y]$

$E[X|Z]=X$

but in general $E[X|Y]$ is different from $X$.